JBPM Tables Insertion Issue (Postgres+jbpm-5.5+java7)
I have use case where I'm creating the process and after some time I'm staring the process with jbpm 5.5.
Once I create the process , jbpm will internally do insertion to few tables like SessionInfo,..etc.
The same way when I start the process , jbpm will internally do insertion to few tables like ProcessInstanceLog,..etc.
This Exact functionality working fine with mssql from long time.
So recently I'm Migrating my DataBase from mssql to postgres then I found the below Issue.
Once I started the Process jbpm not inserting the values to ProcessInstanceLog table, because of this my workflows were failing(since I'm using this table data internally to gather some info). But For some how After my process failed then jbpm inserting values into this tables.
This insertion stuff done by jbpm internally, I'm not having any control over it.
some guidance is appreciated
